# Solr indexing using c++

Tags: c++, solr

i want to index data using curl command in c++
the curl command i am running through linux is getting updated in solr but not via c++ code 
curl command is

curl http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection2/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '[{"id":"4456", "to":"Life is to.", "cc":"unknown ", "subject":"Life"}]'

and c++ code i m trying to execute is not updating the solr

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init(); 
CURLcode res;
static const char *postthis="'[{\"id\":\"4123\",\"from\":\"tarana\", \"to\":\"anuja\", \"cc\":\"unknown cc\",\"bcc\":\"unknown bcc\", \"src_ip\":\"192.168.0.156\",\"dst_ip\":\"192.168.0.40\",\"dst_port\":\"5454\",\"dst_port\":\"4545\",\"subject\":\"abc def ghi jhkl\",\"content\":\"this is testing\",\"interfaceid\":\"1\",\"locationid\":\"1\",\"date_time\":\"2014-12-31T01:59:59Z\"}]'";
static const char *postthis1= "http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection2/update?commit=true ";
static const char *postthis2= "'Content-type: application/json'";
struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
logger.LogError("postthis %s",postthis);
logger.LogError("postthis1 %s",postthis1);
logger.LogError("postthis2 %s",postthis2);
//curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,postthis1 );

    list = curl_slist_append(list, "-H");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, postthis2);
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "-d");


     //if we don't provide POSTFIELDSIZE, libcurl will strlen() by itself 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);



    // Perform the request, res will get the return code
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    //Check for errors 
    if(res != CURLE_OK){
        logger.LogError("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }else if(res == CURLE_OK){
        logger.LogError("res is CURLE_OK");
    }

//always cleanup 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, you should show your own effort into writing the c++ code, what problems you ran into, or where you're stuck.

Comment: @renemilk kindly have a look on the code i hav tried

Comment: You should edit your question to add the code, not add it as an answer.

Comment: @renemilk i hope now that is fine with u

Comment: i m getting res = CURLE_OK as output but not showing the result in solr

Comment: I am not asking this of you for myself, but so others have a chance to help you. Your last comment should also, again, go into an edit of the question.